# I planning to to travel to Croatia and Germany as a tourist. Do I need two separate visas or one multiple-entry Schengen visa?

Tags: schengen, croatia

I am entering the Schengen area from Croatia, staying there for 10 days. I will then travel to Germany for 5 days and exit from Vienna airport (no stay in Austria). Do I need to apply separate visas for the Schengen area and Croatia or will a multiple-entry visa applied at the German consulate do?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need a Schengen uniform visa (C) for two or multiple entries.

> Do I need to apply for Croatian visa if I have a valid Schengen visa?
>
> If you hold a valid Schengen uniform visa (C) for two or multiple
>   entries, valid for all Schengen Area member states, whose period of
>   validity covers your stay in Croatia, and if you have not used all of
>   the days in the Schengen Area (i.e. you need to have at least one day
>   left of the approved number of days; and at least one entry in case of
>   a double-entry visa), you do not require an (additional) Croatian visa
>   for transit through or intended stays in the territory of the Republic
>   of Croatia not exceeding 90 days in any 180-day period.

[Link](http://www.vfsglobal.com/Croatia/India/faqs.html)

Comment: Thank you for the response, i just have one question in my mind does it matters if i enter through Croatia and then go to germany? I meant to say that is first entry in a schengen compulsory?

Comment: And so basically i need to apply for a 5 day visa with validity of 15 days?

Comment: @AnkitNagar you just need a C visa for 2 or multiple entries, so a single entry visa will not be enough, you'd need a Croatian visa then. Currently Croatia is on course to be a Schengen country in 2019 so in the coming years you wont need to worry. Your first port of entry does NOT need to be the country which issued you a Schengen visa. But you could run into problems getting your visa as you are spending more time outside Germany  than, id probably advise you spend more time in Germany than you do in Croatia.